# Access to "parent.parent" property in FireFox, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, callback, cross-browser

I have a structure with nested iframes. It looks like this:

- Domain1
- -> iframe: Domain2
- --> iframe: Domain1 (loaded from Domain2)

There is a callback function on Domain1:

```
window.successCallback = function(){console.log("OK!");}
```

I need to call it from second nested iframe.

This works fine with Chrome and Safari (calling from "iframe: Domain1 (loaded from Domain2)"):

```
window.parent.parent.successCallback();
```

But doesn't work with FireFox.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Try [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.top). And please, define "doesn't work".

Comment: The same with `top`. "doesn't work" means nothing happens. Callback is not running.

Comment: Usually something happens, at least an error message occurs to the console?